# Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks - Unexpected Launch Interstitials in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, admob

How to resolve ***`Layout Encourages Accidental Clicks`*** - ***`Unexpected Launch Interstitials`*** in a Flutter app?